# Sending SMS data from broadcastreceiver to a python server over a TCP Socket

Tags: android, python

I have a broadcast receiver set up to listen for any SMS Received. I want to send this data over a socket back to a python server I have running on my local machine. I've set up a Toast notification to prove to my self that the broadcast receiver works whenever it receives a SMS. Before i added the sending data over a socket the toast would appear inside or outside the application, but after adding the socket portion the toast not only does the data not get sent over the socket but the toast doesn't show up either.

Here is my SMSReciever.java

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
        for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
            smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
        }


        //---"From: " +smsMessage[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress() + "  Text: " + smsMessage[0].getDisplayMessageBody();

        // show first message
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "From: " +smsMessage[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress() + "  Text: " + smsMessage[0].getDisplayMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();


        Socket socket;
        try {
            socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 7000);
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();       
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);         

            output.println("Hello from Android");
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   


       /*
      try{
        Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2",7000);
        DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DOS.writeUTF("From: " +smsMessage[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress() + "  Text: " + smsMessage[0].getDisplayMessageBody());
        socket.close();
     } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
     }
    */
    }
}
```

and here is the python server which listens for connection and prints out the data recieved onto the terminal

server.py

```
from socket import *

HOST = "127.0.0.1" #local host
PORT = 7000 #open port 7000 for connection
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(2) #how many connections can it receive at one time
print "Server started at 127.0.0.1:7000"
conn, addr = s.accept() #accept the connection
print "Connected by: " , addr #print the address of the person connected
while True:
    data = conn.recv(5084) #how many bytes of data will the server receive
    print "Received: ", repr(data)
conn.close()
```

Comment: So... What's the issue? Toast doesn't show up?

Comment: no, the server never recieves the data from android app.

Comment: In other languages I've done when you bind to a host it binds to the interface. Are you binding to the loopback interface when you want to bind to the NIC interface? Also logcat does not show any exceptions?

Comment: Additionally I believe on ICS and up this will crash as you are doing network on main.

Comment: How do i bind my python server to loopback? also what do you mean doing network on main? my main activity calls this smsreciever class then i do the network connection inside the class everytime it recives a incoming sms

Comment: Not sure on the first one, haven't done it on python (or if python is high level enough to just listen to all). Your broadcast receiver (if I recall) still runs on the main (UI) thread. Theres no logcat messages? Your socket object is what is doing the network operation.

Comment: Your app runs on an emulator as you are using 10.0.2.2 as ip address. How do you manage to let it receive an sms? Normally your app would crash with a NetworkOnMainThreadException opening a socket in the main thread.

Comment: I use the emulator control to send it SMSs

Comment: I've Fixed the sending the socket by sending it in a thread, the problem now is that the socket wont close even after socket.close() is called, my python server recives and endless amount of empty data ('')